# Unexpected value from File read

Tags: c, operating-system

I have a file `y.txt` that contains the text `abcdefgh`

this code convert file descriptor(`int fd`) to file pointer (`FILE*`), and tries to read from it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int fd = open("y.txt",O_RDONLY);

    printf("%d",fd);
    fp=fdopen(fd,"r");
    close(fd);
    char a[5];
    a[4]='\0';
    fread(a,2,1,fp);
    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

The program outputs `p` instead of `ab`, as it should if it is reading from the begining of `y.txt`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: ok i know its a bad one and i am really sorry but please clear me that why when i convert fd to file pointer why it is not giving me the correct answer .It is giving me the p but y.txt contains:abcdefg

Comment: maybe try [`fopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) instead of `open`/`fdopen`

Comment: yano: fopen not use file descriptor to open a file .I am just converting file descriptor to file pointer

Comment: Instead of NUL-terminate your string using `a[4]='\0';` (you only `fread` 2 elements) initialize it to 0: `char a[5] = {0};`

Comment: a) don't close the file before you read from it, and b) put a `\n` at the end of each `printf` statement, and c) read **4** characters to fill the string, with `fread(a,4,1,fp);`

Comment: It does not work Keine Lust .Now it is showing nothing as output.

Comment: Thank you so so much for your help Weather Vane

Comment: right, `fopen` returns a file pointer. I don't expect it to fix your problem,, just less code than `open`/`fdopen`

Answer (score 2):

I see a problem with your code. You `close(fd)` before you are done with `fp`, which is probably causing your calls to `fread` to fail. This is because when you use `fdopen`:

> The file descriptor is not dup'ed.

meaning that the underlying file that `fp` is trying to read from gets closed when you run `close(fd)`. To fix this, you can remove the call to `close` and add a call to [`fclose`](http://www.skrenta.com/rt/man/fclose.3.html) which should close `fd` as well.

if you really just want a `FILE *` you should just be able to use [`fopen`](http://www.skrenta.com/rt/man/fopen.3.html) to open it, skipping the `fd` all together.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your code:

```
char a[5];
a[4]='\0';
fread(a,2,1,fp);
```

This gives you a 5 character string. It is an "auto" variable and is not initialized. Then you terminate the string with a `'\0'`. Good. Then you fread one item of size 2. So bytes 3 and 4 are still garbage. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few corrections to the program, as commented in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>                         // added header
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int fd = open("y.txt",O_RDONLY);

    printf("%d\n",fd);                  // add a newline for clarity
    fp=fdopen(fd,"r");
    //close(fd);                        // do not close before reading!
    char a[5];
    a[4]='\0';
    fread(a,4,1,fp);                    // read 4 chars to fill the string space
    printf("%s\n",a);                   // add a newline for clarity
    close(fd);                          // close after reading

    return 0;
}
```

File input:

```
abcde
```

Program output:

```
3
abcd
```

Although it would be better in the first place to have the simpler

```
FILE *fp = fopen("y.txt", "r");
```